# Node.js Method Not Allowed

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new at Node.js and I can't diagnose how this problem arises. I'm trying to update the data in my database. It is blocked at client side level with `HTTP 405`.

I've looked various topics online about this and nothing helped. The `SQL code` is working fine but when I try to submit the data onto the server it's blocked. I'm kinda lost since it doesn't logged the details into the console of server.

Also, I'm getting an error on the `res.redirect` that says can't set headers after they sent to the client. I'm not sure if that affects this code but I think not since I've commented it and the code still works.

**ups.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { StatusCodes, ReasonPhrases } = require("http-status-codes");

module.exports = () => {
    router.post("./routes/ups", async (req, res) => {
      if(
        req.body == null ||
        req.body.id == null ||
        req.body.av == null
      ) {
        return res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json({
          status: StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST,
          title: ReasonPhrases.BAD_REQUEST,
          data: {
            error: "Invalid data provided",
          }
        });
      }

      var id = req.body.id;
      var av = req.body.av;

      //Perform Query Ops
      var sql = "UPDATE `pc_status` SET available = " + av + " WHERE `id` = " + id + "";
      db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
        console.log('record inserted');
        console.log(req.body.id);
        console.log(req.body.av);
        //res.redirect(201 ,'/');
      });

    });
    return router;
};
```

**index.js**

```
app.use(require('./routes/ups.js')());
```

Client-side
**script.js**

```
function testUpload(payload) {
    return fetch("http://localhost:3000/ups", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      mode: "cors",
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });
  }
    //Sample payload
    var payload = {
        id: 24,
        available: 3,
    };
    
    testUpload(payload)
        .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
               if(data.status == 201) {
                    console.log("Good!");
                } else {
                   console.log("Error occured");
                   console.log(data);
                }
           })
            .catch((error) => {
                 console.log(error);
             });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `post` route is defined on `./routes/ups`, while you're sending the request to `ups`. Fix the router's definition and you should be OK:

```js
router.post("/ups", async (req, res) => {
    // router's code snipped for brevity's sake
```

Comment: This code worked but I'm wondering why the server still returns `HTTP 405`?

Comment: @SandrenTroyMilante your client code sends a POST request to `/ups`. If the server doesn't define such a route, you'll get a 405.